# Pressing Enter Key to Login in WPF windows.

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I know that assigning the button to the AcceptButton property in a form would allow me to submit the form in Windows Forms. The problem I'm having is that I'm using a WPF Window as the login screen and I don't know how to make the button work when the Enter Key is pressed. There isn't an AcceptButton Property for WPF Windows. Any Help?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set [IsDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `True`.

```
<Button IsDefault="True"/>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a Button is the default
>   button. A user invokes the default button by pressing the ENTER key.

Comment: Thanks so much Rohit Vats and Steve!